# optimizing conversion between string and date

Tags: c#

I was wondering if there was a more efficient way of taking strings that represent dates with the pattern being `mmddyy` or `mmd yy` or `m d yy` and converting them into a DateTime object?

`111110` would be `11 11 10`

`111 10` would be `11 1 10`

`1 1 10` would be `1 1 10`

The spaces are either ' ' or '\0' (the input I am given is not very clean)

This is what I have so far, which works for all cases.

```
//Converts a given input string into a valid date
private DateTime convertToDateFromString(string dateString)
{
  int length = dateString.Length;
  int month = 1;
  int day = 1;
  int year = 1;
  bool gotMonth = false;
  bool gotDay = false;
  bool gotYear = false;
  char c = ' ';
  char peek = ' ';
  string buffer = "";
  DateTime bufferDate;
  int count = 0;

  try
  {
    for (int i = 0; i < dateString.Length; i++)
    {
      c = dateString[i];
      if ((i + 1) < dateString.Length)
        peek = dateString[i + 1];
      else
        peek = '\0';

      if (c != ' ' && c != '\0')
      {
        buffer += c;
        count++;
        if ((peek == ' ' || peek == '\0' || count == 2) && gotMonth == false)
        {
          count = 0;
          gotMonth = true;
          month = int.Parse(buffer);
          buffer = null;
        }
        else if ((peek == ' ' || peek == '\0' || count == 2) && gotDay == false && gotMonth == true)
        {
          count = 0;
          gotDay = true;
          day = int.Parse(buffer);
          buffer = null;
        }
        else if ((peek == ' ' || peek == '\0' || count == 2) && gotYear == false && gotMonth == true && gotDay == true)
        {
          count = 0;
          gotYear = true;
          year = int.Parse(buffer);
          buffer = null;

          if (year >= 80 && year <= 99)
            year += 1900;
          else if (year >= 0 && year <= 79)
            year += 2000;
        }
      }
    }
    bufferDate = new DateTime(year, month, day);
  }
  catch (System.Exception ex)
  {
    bufferDate = new DateTime(1, 1, 1);
  }

  return bufferDate;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a one-liner for you:

```
    private DateTime convertToDateFromString(string dateString)
    {
        DateTime bufferDate;

        return DateTime.TryParseExact(
            dateString,
            new[] { "MMddyy", "MMd yy", "M d yy" },
            CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
            DateTimeStyles.None,
            out bufferDate)
            ? bufferDate
            : new DateTime(1, 1, 1);
    }
```

With more than one line:

```
    private DateTime convertToDateFromString(string dateString)
    {
        var allowedFormats = new[] { "MMddyy", "MMd yy", "M d yy" };
        DateTime parsedDate;
        var couldParse = DateTime.TryParseExact(
            dateString,
            allowedFormats,
            CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
            DateTimeStyles.None,
            out parsedDate);

        if (couldParse)
        {
            return parsedDate;
        }

        return new DateTime(1, 1, 1); // or throw an exception
    }
```

Comment: The idea is good but the implementation is unreadable. You should use some line breaks.

Comment: Yes, have some.

Comment: Thanks :) Some temporary variable are also useful. I hope you wouldn't mind the edit but I didn't want to write it as a new asnwer.

Comment: Now you're pushing it :)

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I found after more research (Stack Overflow)

```
private DateTime convertToDateFromString(string s)
{
  string[] formats = new string[] { "MMddyy", "MMd yy", "M d yy" };
  string dateString = s.Replace('\0', ' ');
  dateString = dateString.Trim();

  int spaces = dateString.Count(c => c == ' ');
  DateTime date = DateTime.ParseExact(dateString, formats[spaces], null);

  return date;
}
```

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8086726/converting-a-string-to-a-date-in-c-sharp/8086902#8086902